# Laravel Displaying Date/Count with GroupBy

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to display a count of scripts that have been sent through for a specific doctor, broken down by month/year. However, while I can get it to display the `count()` correctly, I cannot get it to display the month/year.

**I also would like to display months where there is no activity, if possible.**

**controller**

```
$doctor = Doctor::findOrFail($id);
$script_counts = $doctor
    ->scripts()
    ->orderBy('prescribe_date', 'desc')
    ->get()
    ->groupBy(function ($script) {
        return Carbon::parse($script->prescribe_date)->format('m/Y');
    });
```

**blade**

```
@foreach ($script_counts as $script_count)
    <tr>
        <td>{{date('F Y', strtotime($script_count->prescribe_date))}}</td>
        <td>{{$script_count->count()}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Displays error: `Property [prescribe_date] does not exist on this collection instance.`

If I exchange the first cell where it should display `January 2018` etc., and just output `{{$script_count}}`, it will display the full object.

Comment: `$script_count` is not a single object, it is a `Collection`, which is why `->count()` works, but `->prescribe_date` doesn't. Maybe try `$script_count->first()->prescribe_date`?

Comment: @TimLewis that helps, thank you! I had tried `->first()` at the end, but I see now why that failed. However, is there any way to display the months with no data in them and set them to 0 count?

Comment: No problem. And not with the logic you currently have; you'd have to loop each month and cross-reference existence of a `$script_count` for that month. So essentially an `@foreach($months AS $month)` combined with an `@if(...)` (not 100% on the logic for checking existence, you'll have to play with that) and an `@else` to display non-existence.

Comment: Or you could leverage the logic for getting `$months` to your Controller and include querying/filtering query results for the current `$month`, etc etc. Lots of approaches, but might be a bit broad.